# Get an attribute value of specific property

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

I have a class with published props which I serialize into XML.

```
MyAttr = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  FName: string;
public
  constructor Create(const Name: string);
  property Name: string read FName write FName;
end;

MyClass = class(TPersistent)
private
  FClassCaption: string;
published
  [MyAttr('Class')]
  property ClassCaption: string read FClassCaption write FClassCaption;
end;
```

Since XML size is crucial, I use attributes to give shorter name for property (i.e I can't define a property named 'Class').
Serialization implemented the following way:

```
lPropCount := GetPropList(PTypeInfo(Obj.ClassInfo), lPropList);
for i := 0 to lPropCount - 1 do begin
  lPropInfo := lPropList^[i];
  lPropName := string(lPropInfo^.Name);

  if IsPublishedProp(Obj, lPropName) then begin
    ItemNode := RootNode.AddChild(lPropName);
    ItemNode.NodeValue := VarToStr(GetPropValue(Obj, lPropName, False));
  end;
end;
```

I need condition like: if property marked with MyAttr, get "MyAttr.Name" instead of "lPropInfo^.Name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function to get your attribute name from the given property (wrote it in a minute, probably needs some optimization):

```
uses
  SysUtils,
  Rtti,
  TypInfo;

function GetPropAttribValue(ATypeInfo: Pointer; const PropName: string): string;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  Aprop: TRttiProperty;
  attr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  Result := '';

  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;

  typ := ctx.GetType(ATypeInfo);

  for Aprop in typ.GetProperties do
  begin
    if (Aprop.Visibility = mvPublished) and (SameText(PropName, Aprop.Name)) then
    begin    
      for attr in AProp.GetAttributes do
      begin
        if attr is MyAttr then
        begin
          Result := MyAttr(attr).Name;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
sAttrName:= GetPropAttribValue(obj.ClassInfo, lPropName);
```

So if this function returns empty string it means that property is not marked with MyAttr and then you need to use "lPropInfo^.Name".